# What value type should i declare an object variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a simple object, which is of type `{[key]:[[array]], [key]:[[array]]}`:

```
const types = {
  first: 'type1',
  second: 'type2',
}

const myobj = {
  '[types.first]': [
     ['blue', 'small', true, 200, 300, undefined, 150],
     ['blue', 'large', true, 560, 600, 300, 150],
  ],
  '[types.second]': [
    ['red', 'xlarge', true, 400, 400, 200, 1],
    ['red', 'xxlarge', true, 500, 500, undefined, 2]
  ]
}
```

I need a help for declaring the type of the object, like so:
`const myobj: 'type of the object' = {....}`

Something like `{[key: string]: [[]]}`, but I can't make it work.

Comment: It's easier to talk about code that compiles.  What is `boolean` and `number` here?

Comment: You could do `{[key: string]: any[][]`}, or `{[key: string]: Array<[string, string, boolean, number, number, number | undefined, number}>` if that fits.  Or just leave `myobj` unannotated so the compiler infers its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objects values is actually an array of tuple types, it can be typed as:

```
 { [key: string]: Array<[string, string, boolean, number | undefined, number | undefined, number | undefined, number | undefined]> }
```

[doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Comment: could i convert `[string, string, boolean, ..]` to an interface ?

Comment: @theo no, but to a type, `type row = [string, boolean];` and then `Array<row>`

Answer (score 0):

> I have created an interface of the Object and then pass that interface as a reference so let's say I have this Object

```
"market_actions": [{
"link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D2796249422649106588",
"name": "Inspect in Game..."
}]
```

> This is what the type for the following Object looks like

```
export interface IDescription {
market_actions: IDAction[]
}
export interface IDAction {
link: string
name: string
}
```

Comment: Our objects have an important difference, as mine is an object with array properties, while yours is an array of objects.